# arcgis map stuck on mouse drag out side of web browser control

Tags: javascript, dom-events, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a problem in JavaScript with map getting stuck in pan mode.

1. I am using maps in desktop application (in Internet Explorer).
2. Drag map and take mouse outside of browser control and then release mouse button.
3. Enter mouse again in browser control, the map is stuck in pan mode -- when I move arrow, map also moves with arrow even while the mouse button is not held down.

[image: Gif Image Here]

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you having this problem in all browsers (e.g. IE, Chrome, etc.)?

Comment: Erica I have add gif image and i am facing this problem in IE

Comment: waiting for the solution.